# OrientDB Equal Query not returning results

Tags: orientdb

I ran a query like this:

```
select urlName from User where urlName like 'Nkj-Fm20%';
```

Which returns one record.

But when I run a query like this:

```
select * from User where urlName = 'Nkj-Fm20'
```

No record is found.

Can you help me?

Comment: There must not be any records that have the exact value of `Nkj-Fm20`. That *is* what the second query does.

Answer (score 1):

the `like` operator allow usage of `%` jolly character, while the `=` doesn't. So with your second query it returns only the users with the exact urlName `Nkj-Fm20`.

Ivan